# JSON to Google Charts

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json, google-visualization

I am trying to construct `google charts` using a `ajax` response form `PHP` file. Following is the output of `alert` in my `javascript`

```
{"cols":[{"id":"5","label":"LISTING","type":"number"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"1"}]}]}
```

When I used the following code to construct the graph i get the error `Data table is not defined.`

```
function drawBarChartAll(totalclientstatus) {
        alert(totalclientstatus);
        //eval ( 'var jsonobject = totalclientstatus;'); 
        //var json = google.visualization.DataTable.toJSON(totalclientstatus)
        var data = google.visualization.DataTable(totalclientstatus);

        var options = {
            'width':670,
            'height':310,

            hAxis: {title: 'Year',  titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}}
            //chartArea:{left:20,top:20,width:"70%",height:"100%"}
        };


        // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('barchartall'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
```

What am i doing wrong ? I am using the following `php` to construct the `JSON`

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($agent_result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {
        $columns = array();
        $reports['cols'][] = array(id => "{$row['statusid']}"
            , label => "{$row['status']}"
            , type => "number");
        $columns['c'][] = array(v => $row['total']);
        $reports['rows'][] = $columns;
    }
 return json_encode($reports);
```

The `ajax` response is

```
{"totalclientstatus":"{\"cols\":[{\"id\":\"5\",\"label\":\"LISTING\",\"type\":\"number\"}],\"rows\":[{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"1\"}]}]}"}
```

Comment: Are you using `google.setOnLoadCallback`?

Comment: yes i am using that to call the ajax and the ajax in turn calls the `drawBarChartAll()`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess you missed the 'new' :

> var data = new google.visualization.DataTable( ...

Comment: You are right. Now i get another error `Not enough columns given to draw the requested chart.`

Comment: Which way did you do this?  Did you build the json on the server and parse it on the client side and insert it using google.visualization.DataTable or did you build the raw json from scratch and just load the json using google.visualization.DataTable(json); ???  The problem I found is that php will not allow assiciative arrays with the same key (duh!) so you can't build the json string using the json_encode function and get multile lines on the chart.

Comment: O holy cr**, I was looking for this small comment for like 3 hours, thank you so much!!!! :D